# Do I have to pray tahajjud prayer after waking up from deep sleep?

Tags: tahajjud

Assalamu Alaikum,

I heard from some people that tahajjud prayer should be performed after waking up from deep sleep. But also read in some other places that it is not mandatory to wake up from deep sleep, even we can pray after a 5 minutes nap. What is the procedure please somebody enlighten me.

If I fall asleep early at night I can't wake up for tahajjud, so I used to practice it often without deep sleep.

JazakAllah Khair.

Answer (score 1):

Tahajjud is the wake up after sleeping, and so is called the prayer of a person slept then woke up, **and whoever mentioned it has to be after sleeping did not mention a deep or light sleep.**

Then Tahajjud is part of "Qeyam Al-Lail" and the best part of Qeiam is at the last one-third, qeyam does not require sleeping.

So If you can sleep early and wake up later for prayer that will be the best, (in Al-Qurtubi mentioned that was how the prophet prayed) but if that is hard and you fear missing the prayer, then pray even without sleeping (which is not required for Qeyam Al-Lail )and Allah knows your neyah.